# IP Address difference?

Tags: networking, ip

Noticed a strange behaviour.

My System IP is `10.99.60.149`. (`ipconfig/all`)

I was trying to make online payment, there it was displayed as "`Your IP Address : 202.45.7.163`"

How is this possible? Can anyone explain?

Comment: The later one is your public IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is your internal IP and the later one is your public IP address(aka, external IP).

In a home network or a corporate network, devices are usually assigned "internal" IP addresses by a Network Address Translator(NAT) located within your router or modem. The NAT hides the internal IP addresses from websites, making the entire home network appear to outside computers to have a single, "external" IP address. In this case, public IP address is the external IP address assigned to your home.

You can find your public IP using Google's api using [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=IP%20Address) link

Answer (score 1):

The first one is local to your network, the second is as the internet sees it through your ISP. You can check against http://whatismyipaddress.com/, which gives your internet IP address.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a domain, or behind a router you have intranet IP Address which is an IP to identify a computer *within* the "local network" in other words "inside your domain". These IPs are usually 10.0.something, or 192.168.something.
On the other hand, there's the internet which is your connection to the world wide web through your ISP (Internet Service Provider). That one is your "global" or "globally visible" IP address.
For a better understand, let's say you live in a condominium. The house is full of flats, having door numbers known inside the condominium only.
 If you refer to e.g. "door 110" everyone inside the house will know which flat you talk about - but nobody in the outside world.
The world will know your house by a different address (IRL a postcode, street, house noumber, city, etc) but only the landlord can tell which flat is the addressee in case someone e.g. sends a letter to a dedicated person inside the condominium.
So the condominium's IP address is the one given by the ISP, the one the world knows as "your household", while the flat door numbers are the ones defined by the landlord (your router or intranet admin, etc).
When a message comes, the landlord can figure out from meta-data attached to the message that it was addressed to you.
To check your "real"/"outside world" IP you can visit e.g. this site: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: You can also check your public IP using google search of "IP Address": https://www.google.com/search?q=Your%20IP%20Address